# statsmodels.regression.linear_model.Regressio... How to fill the values of a column by regression on the other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels, missing-data

I have a data frame `df_atom` that has missing column values, `stock_2021`. I want to fill in the missing values/NaN in the long distance average monthly expenditure column by prediction (regression) using the values in the other columns. Then, replace the NaN values with the new values found.

I tried the following:

```
# Let X = predictor variable and y = target variable
X = pd.DataFrame(df_atom[['stock_2020']])
y = pd.DataFrame(df_atom[['stock_2021']])

# Add a constant variable to the predictor variables
X = sm.add_constant(X)
ypred = model01.predict(X)
```

But I got only nans ...

```
ypred.unique()
array([nan])
```

Comment: `fit()` returns a model. You then call `predict()` on that model, with the relevant X, to get predicted values.

Comment: Many thanks ! Unfortunately I have an error: `TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'params'` I will add the code :)

Comment: If you call `fit()` on one model, then re-create that model, then the new model is no longer fitted. You need to call `predict()` on the same model as you called `fit()` on, and you need to give `predict()` the relevant X variables you want to predict.